# Why ejs displays data in one line

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

There is an ejs template that outputs data from mongo, the problem is that it outputs an array in one line even though I am using a li list

route

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const datauser = await User.find({username: req.user.username})
    res.render('result', { User:datauser, title: 'Посещенные страницы'})
    }  catch(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
   }
})
```

ejs

```
        <div class="results">
        <h1 class="resul"><%=title%></h1>
        
        <ul class="litem">
            <% User.forEach(function (User, i) { %>
         <li>
            <%= User.resultat%>   
        </li>
         <% }) %>
        </ul>      
</div>
```

the result is displayed on one line  and
tag  `</ br` results in an error

**thanks in advance**

Comment: Add "display: block" for your list elements in CSS

Comment: placed but didn't work. If I make an array using a variable in the code, then it is displayed as a list, but from mongo for some reason like this